# Externally Control Application Interface

Tags: user-interface, controls, external

There is an application that I use as an audio mixer. It has a GUI which looks like a mixer- some knobs and some faders, etc. If you don't know what I mean here is an example:

[image: an example of mixing software]

I'm searching for a way to control parameters (volume, pan, mute) using `OSC` or `Midi` protocols. This feature isn't a part of the application...

My current solution:

- a python script listens on an internal midi bus
- launch an automator script to hijack the mouse
- make clicks on the application window

This works for toggles (boolean options, like a Mute button)- but it doesn't work for contiguous parameters like a volume slider.

Does anyone have any suggestions or creative solutions for externally controlling parameters that are only available through the application interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look for `sikuli`. It is writte for automated tests and can be used to work with python scripts on any given gui. So it should be possible to read your comands via python script and execute all mouse events from there. Sikuli can search for pictures on the screen and do actions there like press-mouse-button, move-with-pressed-button, simulate keyboard actions and a lot more. Maybe this can be a startpoint.